# ASP.NET Validators - is there a way to call a function in client side when validation ends?!

Tags: javascript, asp.net, validation

Let say there is a RequiredFieldValidator and when validation happens I want to make some changes on the page (like show a hidden div) if validation fails,

Is there a way to call a function in js when the validation ends?! or do you have any other idea?!

Thanks,

Adler!

Answer (score 0):

Why not write your own validator that extends RequiredFieldValidator?

[This tutorial](http://www.codeproject.com/KB/aspnet/CustRequireFieldValidator.aspx) looks like it could help point you in the right direction:

Or you can write  custom client side java validator:

```
<script type="text/javascript" language="javascript">
    function ValidateDropDown(source, arguments) {
        if (arguments.Value === 'NA') {
            arguments.IsValid = false;
        }
    }
</script>

<asp:CustomValidator ID="CoverServerCustomValidator" runat="server" ErrorMessage="<img src='../Themes/WebOrder/Images/weborder_Error.png'>"ToolTip="A Size is Required" Display="Dynamic" CssClass="Error" ValidationGroup="Sizing" OnServerValidate="ValidateDropDown" ControlToValidate="ddlCover" EnableClientScript="true"></asp:CustomValidator>
```

Comment: custom validator is an option but i use the Required field to save the logic and in a regular expresion validator there is more logic and so on..